# Can I Vote Via Absentee Ballot in the 2022 Georgia Run-Off Election?

Tags: united-states, voting, voter-registration, vote-by-mail, georgia

The senate race between [Raphael Warnock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphael_Warnock) and [Hershel Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herschel_Walker) is projected to go to a run-off election, to be held sometime in December. I did not vote in yesterday's election. I am eligible to vote in [Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_(U.S._state)), but I am not yet registered to do so. Can I register to vote and request an absentee ballot in time for the run-off? How can I do so?

Answer (score 18):

Just to add to Rick Smith's answer; no - due to the recent passage of the [Election Integrity Act 2021](https://www.legis.ga.gov/legislation/59827), which reduced the time between a general election and a runoff election from nine weeks to four (section 42 of the act), it is too late to register to vote in the runoff election if you weren't already registered to vote on November 8th.

This is because GA Code § 21-2-224(a) sets the vote registration deadline as the 5th Monday before an election; in this case, November 7th.

Prior to the passage of this act, you would have had sufficient time to register to vote between the initial election and the runoff.

Answer (score 8):

*Q: Can I register to vote and request an absentee ballot in time for the run-off?*

At this point, no.

[2022 Scheduled Elections Calendar of Events](https://www.sos.ga.gov/sites/default/files/forms/2022%20State%20Scheduled%20Elections%20Short%20Calendar.pdf)

> November 7, 2022 - Last day for a person to register and be eligible to vote in the General Election Runoff for Federal Races.

Comment: But _now_ is a good time to register to vote so you can vote in the _next_ election